# How to get an animation to rotate sync image for ammout of time

Tags: ios, core-animation

So I've got an image that I'm using to show the user that a sync is being performed after they tap a button, but can't figure out how to get it to keep spinning for a few seconds rather than one time around....Below are the methods that I'm using to perform the animation. Could someone help me figure out how to get this to rotate for a few seconds?

Thanks in advance!

```
- (void)syncTapped:(UIButton *)standardButton {
    [self animateSynchronization];
    repeatSyncAnimation = YES;
}


-(void)animateSynchronization {
    repeatSyncAnimation = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.23 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        syncImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(syncImage.transform, M_PI_2);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (repeatSyncAnimation) {
            [self animateSynchronization];
            [self stopSynchronizationAnimation];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the `completion` block and just use the `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` option (along with your existing `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` option). And when you want to stop the animation, you can:

```
[syncImage.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Obviously, if you want this to stop after a predetermined amount of time, you can use a `NSTimer` or `dispatch_after`, e.g.:

```
double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [syncImage.layer removeAllAnimations];
});
```

You will have to add an `#import` to the start of your `.m` file, though, for the compiler to recognize this `removeAllAnimations` method:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```